# PHP welcome screen echo username

Tags: php, authentication, get

I am building a welcome user page - after my user logs in, I want on each page to echo the name of the user. however I am having difficulty, after looking at various forums I have resulted into posting my code in the hope someone may have an idea where I am going wrong.

I have 2 key pages - Login and the Index page.

```
Login.php page
    <?php
    session_start();
    require("includes/connect.php");
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <title>Login</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login.css">

            <!--Cited Bootstrap: Responsive web design-->
            <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="container">
                <form class="form-signin" role="form" action="login.php" method="post">
                    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username_login" required autofocus>
                    <input class="form-control" type="password"  placeholder="Password" name="user_password" required>
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
                    <label class="forgotten"><a href="forgottenpass.php">Forgotten password?</a></label>
                </form>

    <?php

    //if an admin or user session is already in progress then dont let them log in, redirect to 'index.php'
    if (isset($_SESSION['admin']) && ($_SESSION['admin'] == true) || isset($_SESSION['user']) && ($_SESSION['user'] == true)) {
        echo "You are already logged in";     
        //if use not logged in then
     }else
        if ( trim($_POST['username_login']) AND trim($_POST['user_password']))
        {
        //if username and password are entered, blank before user fills form
        $usr = (isset($_POST['username_login'])? $_POST['username_login']:null);
        $pwd = (isset($_POST['user_password'])? $_POST['user_password']:null);

        //$usr = mysqli_escape_string($usr); //Prevent against SQL Injection by avoiding "\" being executed
      //  $pwd = mysqli_escape_string($pwd); //Prevent against SQL Injection by avoiding "\" being executed

        if ($usr && $pwd){  
            $epwd = $pwd;
            $q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE UName='$usr' LIMIT 1;";
            $resultset = mysqli_query($conn,$q);
            $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($resultset);

            if ($rowcount==1){ 
                while ($userRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset)){
                    //Get the DB username and password to compare
                    $dataBaseEmail = $userRow['UName'];
                    $dataBasePass = $userRow['Password'];   
                    $userGroup = $userRow['UserLevelID'];

                }

            mysqli_free_result($resultset);
            unset($q);

            //Compare DB user and pass to those entered
            if ($usr == $dataBaseEmail && $epwd == $dataBasePass){
                //Now that we know they are activated ect, we can create a session based on their privlidges 
                if ($userGroup ==1){ //ADMIN load the console 
                    $_SESSION['admin'] = true;
                    //header("Location: admincreateuser.php");
                    echo '<div class="login-error">You are an admin user <a href="adminindex.php">Admin</a>.</div>';

                    //exit;
                }else{ //Normal User
                    $_SESSION['user'] = true;
                    $_SESSION['user'] = $dataBaseEmail;
                    //header ("Location: index.php");
                    echo '<div class="login-error">You are a standard user <a href="index.php">Standard</a>.</div>';
                    //exit;
                    }  
                }else{//user and pass do not match DB
                    echo '<div class="login-error">Incorrect Password, try again</div>';     
                }
            }else{
                echo '<div class="login-error">Error: There is no such user registered on the system. Please check the username and password entered.</div>';
            } 
        }
    }
    ?>
            </div> <!-- /container -->

      </body>
    </html>

Index.php page:

<?php
session_start();
include "includes/header.php";
include "includes/connect.php";
?>

<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Operating system being used:<?php echo $os?></h1>
    <p>Text</p>

<?php echo $os?>
<?php 

echo "Hello" .$_SESSION['user'];
?>
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used `$_SESSION['user']` for two purposes, you can rename any one of the $_SESSION array

Try this,

```
  $_SESSION['user'] = true;
  $_SESSION['userEmail'] = $dataBaseEmail;
```

instead of

```
  $_SESSION['user'] = true;
  $_SESSION['user'] = $dataBaseEmail;
```

And in welcome screen,

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
  echo "Hello" .$_SESSION['userEmail'];
}
```

Comment: Ok I tried this, and then tried to echo $_Session['userEmail'] in my index page. no result.

Comment: Whether you have logged in as normal user or admin user?

Comment: Its working, i just needed to refresh my settings. Brilliant thank you Krish R it now works, star!